# Accessing LDAP Active Directory in ASP.net core is very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap

i am working on .net core project which require authentication to LDAP AD, i'm using Novell library to help me connect to the LDAP AD Server, but when i run the code it's taking around 2 minutes to get the response. Can anyone show me what's wrong? For your information, i'm hosting the .net core project on ubuntu server and the LDAP AD Server is in Windows Azure server. 
Here's the code, thanks.

```
public ADResponse LdapSearch(string server, string filter, string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new LdapConnection { SecureSocketLayer = false })
                {
                    string DN = configuration.GetValue<string>("LdapServer:TeacherDN");
                    if (server == configuration.GetValue<string>("LdapServer:LdapStudent"))
                    {

                        DN = configuration.GetValue<string>("LdapServer:sphStudentDN");
                    }
                    int serverPort = configuration.GetValue<int>("LdapServer:sphLdapPort");

                    string[] attributes = { "name", "mail", "extensionAttribute2", "memberOf" };

                    connection.Connect(server, serverPort);
                    connection.Bind(username, password);
                    if (connection.Bound)
                    {
                        ADResponse data = new ADResponse();

                    LdapSearchQueue queue = connection.Search(DN,
                                    LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB,
                                     filter,
                                     attributes,
                                     false,
                                    (LdapSearchQueue)null,
                                    (LdapSearchConstraints)null);

                    LdapMessage message;
                    while ((message = queue.getResponse()) != null)
                    {
                        if (message is LdapSearchResult)
                        {
                            LdapEntry entry = ((LdapSearchResult)message).Entry;
                            LdapAttributeSet attributeSet = entry.getAttributeSet();
                            System.Collections.IEnumerator ienum = attributeSet.GetEnumerator();
                            while (ienum.MoveNext())
                            {
                                LdapAttribute attribute = (LdapAttribute)ienum.Current;
                                string attributeName = attribute.Name;
                                string attributeVal = attribute.StringValue;

                                if (attributeName == "name")
                                {
                                    data.name = attributeVal;
                                }
                                else if (attributeName == "mail")
                                {
                                    data.mail = attributeVal;
                                }
                                else if (attributeName.ToLower() == "postofficebox")
                                {
                                    data.pobox = attributeVal;
                                }
                                else if (attributeName.ToLower() == "extensionattribute2")
                                {
                                    data.extensionattribute = attributeVal;
                                }
                                else if (attributeName.ToLower() == "memberof")
                                {
                                    data.memberof = attributeVal;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Disconnect();
                    return data;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (LdapException ex)
            {
                // Log exception
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**UPDATE** :
The speed of querying is much faster in windows server, so i've already tried to host it on windows server and the process of querying ldap only take about 5 seconds. Anyone know why is that happen?

**UPDATE** : 
I have tried to access another AD ([From this public test AD](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)) from the ubuntu server and its run smoothly and take only 2 second to query.

**UPDATE :**
Turn out, the AD server de-listing my server IP from their white list that can allow the AD server, after they list my server IP back to the white list i can normally access the AD again.

Comment: What is the filter you are testing with?

Comment: the filter i'm using is the "mail" attribute

Comment: So your `filter` parameter is something like this?: `(mail=someone@domain.com)`

Comment: yes, it is like that

Comment: The `mail` attribute is indexed, so that's not the problem. There is nothing glaring the stands out to me, although I've never used the Novell library. You can step through your code one line at a time, and see which line takes the longest to complete. Visual Studio even tells you how long it's been.

Comment: I just saw your update about Windows Server. Is the Windows Server closer to your AD server?

Comment: No it's not closer to the AD Server, the Windows server and the ubuntu server is in one location (they can communicate through local IP to each other) meanwhile the AD server is at the customer location. I have tried to access another AD (http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) from the ubuntu server and its run smoothly and take only 2 second to query.

Comment: Step through your code then. As you do, see how long each line takes. `queue.getResponse()` should be making a network request, so that line should take the longest. `entry.getAttributeSet()` might be (it really shouldn't have to, but I'm not sure how the Novell library works).